# Displaying custom error pages on different VirtualHosts in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, custom-errors

I have a reverse proxy Apache that is moving the request to a Tomcat servlet.
The configuration on the Virtual Host in Apache is:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
ProxyPass /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
ProxyPassReverse /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1//Site1/ServLet1

ProxyPass /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
ProxyPassReverse /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site1/ServLet1
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially, if it comes to `10.10.10.10` and requests `/Site1/ServLet1`, route it to `/Site1/ServLet1`.

if I add

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
ProxyPass /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
ProxyPassReverse /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1//Site1/ServLet1
ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site1/404.html

ProxyPass /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
ProxyPassReverse /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site1/ServLet1
</VirtualHost>
```

so it will show a custom error for `site1` (I set the ErrorDocument), it will be served to both.

How can I have a different 404 error page per site maintaining this kind of configuration?

Thank

Edit:

if I modify the configuration based on the comments below like:

```
<Location /Site1/ServLet1/>
ProxyPass http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site1/404.html
</Location>
```

Then I can still get to `http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1` but no error page is displayed whatsoever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "different VirtualHosts", since these are in the same one.. but I think you'll want to do something like this (and consider moving the `ProxyPass` statements into the `<Location>` blocks too, if you can):

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
    ProxyPass /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
    ProxyPassReverse /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1

    <Location /Site1>
        ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site1/404.html
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
    ProxyPassReverse /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2

    <Location /Site2>
        ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site2/404.html
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**

To have the `Proxy` statements reside in the location blocks:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
    <Location /Site1>
        ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site1/404.html
    </Location>
    <Location /Site1/ServLet1>
        ProxyPass http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
        ProxyPassReverse http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
    </Location>

    <Location /Site2>
        ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site2/404.html
    </Location>    
    <Location /Site2/ServLet2>
        ProxyPass http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
        ProxyPassReverse http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I added `<Location /Site1>` and when I browse to `Site2` I still see the error for `Site1`. Also adding `ProxyPass` inside the `Location` tags gives me an error `ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.`

Comment: That's correct.  If you're just proxying those specific servlets, then you'll want to define the blocks as `<Location /Site2/ServLet2>` and drop the `/Site2/ServLet2` part from the `Proxy` commands.

Comment: what I want to do is that if the user browses to `10.10.10.10/Site1/ServLet1` then everything is fine, if he browses to  `10.10.10.10/Site1/AnyOtherPage` then display error. This needs to be done per page

Comment: I still get ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location. I'm confused now, could write a little sample or modify the one in your answer?

Comment: See comments on my question. I passes the request via the reverse proxy to `http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1` but it doesn't show any error page

Comment: @MrAleph Edited, try that.

Comment: Still. It doesn't show any error page.

Answer (score 5):

Make it so that each vhost  has it's own VirtualHost definition.

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
    Servername site1.tld
    ProxyPass /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1/Site1/ServLet1
    ProxyPassReverse /Site1/ServLet1 http://1.1.1.1//Site1/ServLet1
    ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site2/404.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
    ServerName site2.tld
    ProxyPass /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site2/ServLet2
    ProxyPassReverse /Site2/ServLet2 http://2.2.2.2/Site1/ServLet1
    ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/site2/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need to ensure that you have a suitable [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) definition.

Comment: I don't have a servername, they are all IP addresses

Comment: I think it would be simpler if you did the name based virtual hosting thing.

Comment: such as? Can you modify your example to show me what you mean'

Comment: @MrAleph It would mean using a different hostname for servlet; `site1.example.com` instead of `example.com/site1/servlet1` - and I agree, that approach might simplify things future changes and maintenance.